# not receiving the data in serializer django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I have problem with sending data via forms
below I will explain more.
here is the code :

View.py

```
def post(self, request,cafe_slug):
    # if request.data[item]is not for item in request.data
    serializer = AddOrderSerializer(self.get_object(), data=request.data)
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})
    serializer.save()
```

request.data in view.py

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['nPIfiEa8RLNXwciHxatFlESQKDtLYrqHQU12YDAVg4AzjXedbSQoOquxzWYU76ve'], '1': ['0'], '2': ['2']}>
```

serialzier.py

```
class AddOrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    item=serializers.CharField()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
```

in HTML I made a loop from all of my items and just the user can field this

```
  <input name={{item.id}} type="number"
                       id="itemCount" min="0" value=0>
```

The problem is in the serializer I get nothing (from validated data) but I have the data in the view.py. what should I do?
is there any way to get int instead of a list in request.data ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with the **Django templating** or **Django rest framework**?

If you're doing REST-based web service stuff ... you should ignore **`request.POST`**.

**`request.data`** returns the parsed content of the **`request body`**. This is similar to the standard **`request.POST`** and **`request.FILES`** attributes.